# How to extract the field by name instead of column number with awk?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a large `gtf`. Here I'm sharing `eg.gtf` that looks like below:

```
chr22   Cufflinks       transcript      10695955        10696708        .       +       .       transcript_id "first_11345700"; gene_id "XLOC_158970"; gene_name "XLOC_158970"; oId "TCONS_00353198"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS369767"; original_gene_id "XLOC_158970";
chr22   Cufflinks       exon    10702915        10703826        .       +       .       transcript_id "first_11345701"; gene_id "ENSG00000277248.1"; gene_name "ENSG00000277248.1"; exon_number "1"; original_gene_id "ENSG00000277248.1";
chr22   Cufflinks       transcript      10702915        10707278        .       +       .       transcript_id "first_11345701"; gene_id "ENSG00000277248.1"; gene_name "ENSG00000277248.1"; oId "TCONS_00353199"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS369769"; original_gene_id "ENSG00000277248.1";
```

With `awk` I extracted the required fields using their column numbers like below:

```
cat eg.gtf | awk 'OFS="\t" {if ($3=="transcript") {print $1,$4-1,$5,$12,$7}}' | tr -d '";'
```

The output looks like below:

```
chr22   10695954    10696708    XLOC_158970 +
chr22   10702914    10707278    ENSG00000277248.1   +
```

Rather than using the column number `12` in `awk` command, I would like to extract the fields with names.

Note: `12th column has different names, starting with E or X or M or N or S`.

How to I get the 12th field without giving the column number `12` in `awk` command? Is there a way to get the 12 field using term `gene_id` which is 11th column?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the GTF file will always have the same internal order in the fields. The fields are defined by tabs, not spaces, so you cannot rely on the 12th field being the gene_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTF is a tab-separated format and you cannot rely on the order of sub-fields. You need to use text parsing instead. I would do it in perl:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane '
    if($F[2] eq "transcript"){
        $gene_id = /gene_id\s*"([^"]+)"/ ? $1 : "None"; 
        print join("\t",$F[0],$F[3]-1,$F[4],$gene_id,$F[6])
    }' file
chr22   10695954    10696708    XLOC_158970 +
chr22   10702914    10707278    ENSG00000277248.1   +
```

This has the advantage of printing "None" in cases where there is no gene name (e.g. non-coding transcripts might not have one, or unknown transcripts etc.).

Comment: Excellent. thanks a lot tendon. small question. Lets say I need `transcript_id` instead of `gene_id`. Just replacing `gene_id` in your code with `transcript_id` works?

Comment: @beginner yes, it should.

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
$3 == "transcript" {
    n = split($NF,tmp,/[; "]+/)
    for ( i=1; i<n; i+=2 ) {
        vals[tmp[i]] = tmp[i+1]
    }
    print $1, $4-1, $5, vals["gene_id"], $7
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
chr22   10695954    10696708    XLOC_158970 +
chr22   10702914    10707278    ENSG00000277248.1   +
```

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot ! very helpful. If you don't mind could you please give some explanation about the code

Comment: @beginner you're welcome. it's pretty basic and common awk code so I'm not sure what to explain - did you have any questions about anything specific?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) while assuming that the input is a tab-delimited file where the 9th field is made up of `;`-delimited key-value fields (keys delimited with a space from the double-quoted value string):

```
mlr --inidx --ifs tab --otsv --headerless-csv-output \
    filter '$3 == "transcript"' then \
    put '$4 -= 1; $9 = gsub($9, "; ", ";"); $9 = gsub($9, "\"", "")' then \
    nest --explode --pairs --across-fields --nested-fs ';'  --nested-ps ' ' -f 9 then \
    cut -o -f 1,4,5,gene_id,7 file.gtf
```

This reads the file as integer-indexed tab-delimited fields and creates header-less tab-delimited data output (TSV).  We can't read the data as TSV as Miller complains about the embedded quotes (you can't have embedded quotes in a field if the field itself isn't quoted).

The processing starts with a `filter` operation that discards any record whose 3rd field is not the string `transcript`.

Using `put`, we then adjust the value of the 4th field by decrementing it by one.  We also remove the space after each `;` in the 9th field (the field with the extra annotations), and all the field's double quotes.

The `nest --explode` operation creates new *named* fields from the data in the 9th field by "exploding" its key-value pairs.

We can then, with `cut`, extract the fields we want, which includes the `gene_id` field.

Output with the data in the question:

```
chr22   10695954        10696708        XLOC_158970     +
chr22   10702914        10707278        ENSG00000277248.1       +
```